# I'll book the restaurant on Tuesday

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Does this mean he will book the restaurant on Tuesday. (reserve it for coming Tuesday, for example).

Or

Does it mean he will make the booking on Tuesday ( On Tuesday, he will make the booking. ( For whenever he want it to be).

Answer (score 1):

The sentence can have either meaning. Grammatically, it would be more elegant for "on Tuesday" simply to modify "will book". However, it is more common to state the date for which the reservation is made, not the date on which the reservation is made.

The sentence can be reworded to remove any ambiguity, e.g.:

- On Tuesday I'll book the restaurant.
- I'll book the restaurant for Tuesday.